# Godel's Incompleteness Theorem and Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, incompleteness

According to Godel's incompleteness theorem, not every problem can be solved using algorithms. How do we know if a problem can be solved using algorithm?
How do we know that NP problems are algorithmically solvable?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the question is asking. If a problem is in NP, it is decidable by a Turing machine (we can explore all polynomial length certificates to see if one of them is correct for the instance at hand)

Answer (score 2):

We know a problem can be solved by an algorithm (it's *computable*) by exhibiting an algorithm that solves it. Or by showing that the problem can be reduced – transformed by an algorithm – into another problem for which we know an algorithm. You can take "algorithm" to mean *program in your favorite programming language*.

NP problems are by definition computable: some machine computes the problem. In the case of problems in NP, the machine is nondeterministic ("NP" stands for "Nondeterministic Polynomial-time"), but the computation performed by this abstract machine can be performed by a deterministic machine, one which takes at worst exponentially longer to arrive at answers.

Comment: Note that "NP" does **not** stand for "Not Polynomial" - this might be tripping up the OP.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Point taken (I added what it stands for). I didn't want to launch into a description of nondeterministic TMs, Church's Thesis and other issues, as I wasn't sure what the source of puzzlement is/was. But if OP has further questions I'm open to them.